# What is the quickest, easiest and lowest cost way to populate a bootstrap modal form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

As an example, I have a table of items with edit buttons on each item:
[image: Table of Edit Items]

I want to populate an edit form in a bootstrap modal as quickly, efficiently and as easily as possible.
Currently, I have tried populating via Javascript into a partial but this is a bit bulky and doesn't suit my needs when there are specific functions, varying inputs and different ways to input data. In some of my tables, the editing functions require 500+ lines of Javascript to calculate and process a bunch of different situations.

I've also tried generating a new modal partial for each item with partial Models but in larger tables with 1000+ items, this tends to lag the page quite a bit or take a significant time to load.

I need a way to quickly populate a modal with as little code as possible. Hopefully, I'd like a globalised way to do this for any given Model.

I also need the ability to populate the form action to do a variety of different things depending on the item.

I've heard that Ajax is a possible way to do this, but as I am relatively new to web development, I am not 100% sure how to do this.

What would be incredibly useful and would solve all my issues, is a way to render the modal AFTER loading of the page and on the input of an edit button.
So page renders -> you click edit on a given item -> it then renders the edit modal. Although I don't think this is possible.

This is just an example modal form:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently, I have tried populating via Javascript into a partial but this is a bit bulky and doesn't suit my needs when there are specific functions, varying inputs and different ways to input data.
>
> I've also tried generating a new modal partial for each item with partial Models

To display editing record in popup modal, we can achieve it either with JavaScript completely or mix using partial view.

If you do not want to generate/populate popup modal for editing row via 100% JavaScript client code, you can try:

1) when you click on edit button, make ajax request to controller action that accepts parameter `Id` of selected item

2) in that action, you can retrieve detailed and expected information of the item you want to edit based on `Id`, and the action would return a partial view

3) in partial view, you can render expected input fields based on your retrieved item information

4) in ajax success callback function, dynamically populate body of popup modal with returned data

Besides, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633022/how-can-i-render-partial-view-as-modal-popup-on-button-click/60647001#60647001) discussed rendering partial view as modal popup, you can refer to it.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect. Thank you so much. Sorry for the duplicate thread. Couldn't seem to find an answer for this. Thanks heaps